# Bing site scan: Avoid Error 403 if index.html is missing the root domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-403

I have a website with the following domain name:

`https://example.com` (there is no index.html in the root domain name)

I have the following redirect based on language detection in .htaccess:

`https://example.com` > `https://example.com/en/index.html` (for English language)
`https://example.com` > `https://example.com/fr/index.html` (for French language)

The user is redirected correctly, but Bing site scan returns error 403 due to the missing index.html in the root domain `https://example.com`. This means that Bing's crawler fails indexing the website. Google's crawler is not affected and can index the website properly.

What are the best solutions to this problem I am experiencing with Bing?

That is my current .htaccess redirect/rewrite

```
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Detect browser's language
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/en/ [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/fr/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an SEO/Webdevelopment (non-programming) question which is better suited to the webmasters stack at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. Please re-ask your question over there. Thanks.

Comment: This is a `.htaccess`, `apache`, and `http-status-code-403` related question. So, I optimised it. Anyway, why a SEO tag is available on stackoverflow with 7794 questions if it cannot be used? This problem can be resolved with a javascript with ease, but I believe it is not the best solution. For clarity: the etymology of programming comes from ancient Greek, and it is formed by the words PRO (before) and GRAPHMA (writing) which mean "written document". Therefore, any document which provides instructions to a machine for performing one or more tasks can be considered programming related. Thanks

Comment: _"This problem can be resolved with a javascript with ease"_ - if the Bing bot requests `/index.html`, and gets a 403 response from your system, then how would you fix that with JavaScript? You should simply make your server respond differently. Make the language-based redirect work when this gets requested as well?

Comment: The javascript would fetch the UA and/or browser language, and redirect the user/crawler accordingly. This way Bing crawler would not get the error 403, but I don't believe this is the best solution as there are shortcomings. With regard to `if the Bing bot requests /index.html, and gets a 403 response`: you can't invoke or call a js function, neither load a script this way. It's needed something such as an .html or .php file in conjunction with a .js. If the server responds differently, as you suggested, I am worried that this could be seen as cloaking and trigger search engine penalties (?)

Comment: _"The javascript would fetch the UA and/or browser language, and redirect the user/crawler accordingly. This way Bing crawler would not get the error 403"_ - so you are talking about _server-side_ JavaScript here then? Because otherwise, the bot already _got_ the 403 response, before any JS could execute on the client side. _"you can't invoke or call a js function, neither load a script this way"_ - I never said that I considered that to be a solution in the first place.

Comment: _"If the server responds differently, [...] I am worried that this could be seen as cloaking"_ - why? The `/index.html` URL is not a "real" one you _want_ indexed or anything anyway. And I also doubt that you explicitly linked to it anywhere, so likely this is just the Bing bot testing a "default".

Comment: A simple `https://example.com/inde.html` embedding a .js would not trigger any error 403  (I already tested this successfully) but I would prefer to avoid .js. An URL redirect/rewrite using the .htaccess file seems to be faster, and maybe would reduce possible compatibility issues with some devices.

Comment: I tested a couple or redirect/rewrite with no joy. The one below is the latest one I tried unsuccessfully:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)/index.html$`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s`
`RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$ https://example.com/en/$1 [R=301,L,NC]`

I hope it is clear with this messy formatting. Are your skills on this better than mine? :)

Comment: @GoemonCode Please update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file. If a 403 is being served then the language redirect has not been implemented correctly - there needs to be a "default". Bing may not be sending an `Accept-Language` header, or one that you are expecting. (Depending on how this is implemented, a language redirect is generally a bad idea for SEO, since the search engine bot is in danger of only being able to crawl one language.)

Comment: **Regarding cloaking:** This technique makes crawlers to access content different from that accessed by users and is harshly sanctioned by search engines when it is detected. _Ref: https://postcron.com/en/blog/google-penalties/_

Comment: Is this a single page website?

Comment: @MrWhite I added the relevant portion in the .htaccess in the question above. Thanks

There is a structure like the following: https://example.com/en/ , https://example.com/en/sub1, https://example.com/en/ sub2, https://example.com/en/etc.

Comment: [Cross-site post on the Webmasters stack.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142493/bing-site-scan-avoid-error-403-if-index-html-is-missing-the-root-domain-name)